# contact form 7 wordpress plugin message condition

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I use the contact form 7 Plugin in Wordpress, now I have a 10 radio buttons.

Now I want that the mail which is sended to the user conatins a link to a PDF File.

But The URL should be different for each Radio Button. Can I have conditions in the Mail?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know CF7, but it looks like it is extensible. Were you hoping for a admin site configuration answer, or code you can put in a plugin to do this?

Comment: this plugin will work for you : https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/